# PHP MYSQL match and output

Tags: php, mysql, match

I'm having a really hard time trying to figure out what I'm doing here. Let me explain first what I'm trying to do and what I'm getting so far.

What I have:

So far I have what I need in the way of grabbing data from yahoo to populate within a search. It is a simple form that asks for a visitor to input a symbol in which will then spit out quote information.

My goal:

I'm trying to correlate my database to also show my database information if the stock symbol is something I have information on. So say a visitor enters the stock symbol "hig" into the form I'd like to call my table 'stockpicks' to see if there is a match in the column 'symbol'. If this is the case i'd like to output other specific data from that table from other columns such as 'notes' for example.

Here is the active sample : http://www.stocksandstocks.com/stock-quotes.php
I can't seem to figure out the relationship between the two and how to get it right. Below is what I have so far.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); //this is for debugging, remove if you dont need anymore
ini_set("display_errors", 1); //this is for debugging, remove if you dont need anymore
$searchoutput = "";
$ticker = "goog";

if (isset($_POST['get_quote'])) {
$ticker = $_POST['ticker'];
}

$open = fopen("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$ticker&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv", "r");
$quote = fread($open, 1000);

fclose($open);

$quote = str_replace("\"", "", $quote);
$quote = explode(",", $quote);

$quote_0 = ($quote[0]);
$quote_1 = ($quote[1]);
$quote_2 = ($quote[2]);
$quote_3 = ($quote[3]);
$quote_4 = ($quote[4]);
$quote_5 = ($quote[5]);
$quote_6 = ($quote[6]);
$quote_7 = ($quote[7]);
$quote_8 = ($quote[8]);

echo "<div class='symbol'><div class='quote'>Company: $quote_0</div></div>";
echo "<div class='row'><div class='quote'>Last trade: $$quote_1</div>";
echo "<div class='quote'>Date: $quote_2</div>";
echo "<div class='quote'>Time: $quote_3</div>";
echo "<div class='quote'>From Previous: $$quote_4</div></div>";
echo "<div class='row'><div class='quote'>Open: $$quote_5</div>";
echo "<div class='quote'>High: $$quote_6</div>";
echo "<div class='quote'>Low: $$quote_7</div>";
echo "<div class='quote'>Volume: $quote_8</div></div>";

if (isset($_POST['get_quote']) && $_POST['get_quote'] != "") {
$ticker = $_POST['ticker'];
    $get_quote = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['get_quote']);

$sqlCommand = "(SELECT id, symbol as sym FROM stockpicks WHERE symbol LIKE '%$get_quote%')";

        include_once("storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php");
        $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count > 1){
$search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$get_quote/strong><hr />$sqlCommand<hr />";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $id = $row["id"];
   $sym = $row["sym"];
   $search_output .= "Item ID: $id - $sym<br />";
                } // close while
} else {
$search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$get_quote</strong><hr />$sqlCommand";
}
}

?>                              
                                    <div class="form">  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>">
                                        Get Quote: <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="ticker"/>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Get Quote" name="get_quote" />
                                        </form></div>
                                        Enter any valid stock quote such as:<br>
                                        aapl<br>
                                        hog<br>
                                        rimm<br>
                                        rht<br>
                                        <?php echo $search_output ;?>
                                </div>
```

Comment: why do you have `$$` in your variables? are you using variable variable names?

Comment: I just removed the $$...it was just a copy and paste to make my life easier. Something I was going to remove in the final cut. Price requires $ signs as well as others. Just forgot to remove them. I've edited and removed them though. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: so your getting the data from yahoo ok right? what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to make the connection between user input and matching that to see if it exists within the table stock picks in the column 'symbol'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your condition here `if($count > 1){` to read `if($count >= 1){` then you will be able to read the rows that are returned by the query.

second issue you having is a miss labeled variables. You need use the value of `ticker`, right now your using '`qet_quote`' which is the name of a button.

```
$ticker = $_POST['ticker'];
$get_quote = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['ticker']);

$sqlCommand = "(SELECT id, symbol as sym FROM stockpicks WHERE symbol LIKE '%$get_quote%')";
```

Comment: Hi DevZer0 thanks for the quick response and help. Can you try the active example to see what my issue is. The active test page is located in the link in the original post. To get to where I'm at can you enter hig into the search. It will dispaly what i'm seeing.

Comment: Yes I chaned the count to >= as directed

Comment: your `$sqlCommand` variable is echoing out `(SELECT id, symbol as sym FROM stockpicks WHERE symbol LIKE '%Get Quote%')` which tells me your not passing the value properly

Comment: I think that's what I'm having an issue with. As you said I'm not passing the value.

Comment: Thanks so much I didn't notice that at all. I'm still having a problem with         "$sqlCommand variable is echoing out (SELECT id, symbol as sym FROM stockpicks WHERE symbol LIKE '%Get Quote%') which tells me your not passing the value properly". Which we had an issue with earlier.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32786/discussion-between-hire-logo-and-devzer0)